# How can i diagnostic why Azure VM fallen "This virtual machine is stopping and deallocating as requested by an authorized user or process."

Tags: azure, server, virtual-machine

I use Azure- windows VM for running some services, the services are very stable(after testing).
The server run one day and after that he has fallen and i get this message.
 **

**Diagnose and solve problems**

[image]

**In Activity log**

[image]

**Resource health**

[image]

**Solved**

The problem was in 'Auto-shutdown' it was enabled to 'Scheduled shutdown'. you can find it under - HOME --> VM --> Auto-shutdown(under the title Operations).

Comment: Do you try to select the `Timespan` to last two weeks in the Activity Log, is it still nothing? It should have `Event initiated by` some users or service.

Comment: Thank you, i updated my Activity Log, but still i didn't understand why it's fallen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Activity Log, we can see the [Azure Lab Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lab-services/lab-services-overview) initiated the VM deallocation.

When you create a Lab Service in Azure, there is an option for you to **automatically shut down virtual machines** when users disconnect. It's probably the reason. This could help save costs.

[image]

It's the same **Lab policy** when you create template VMs in the lab Account or change it later.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!!  I think i found the problem, by what you said- but the problem was in 'Auto-shutdown' it was enabled to 'Scheduled shutdown'   in HOME --> VM --> Auto-shutdown(under the title Operations).